# HTTP Server causing HTTP Client to return stream error: INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: http, go, http2

I have two services running: an API (in this case, the 'server') and a client application. I have the server configured like so:

```
r := CreateApiRouter()
var certManager *autocert.Manager
certManager = &autocert.Manager{
    Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
    HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist(utilities.ServeHost),
    Cache: autocert.DirCache(utilities.CertCacheDir),
}

srv := &http.Server{
    Handler:           r,
    Addr:       ":" + utilities.ServePort,
    ReadHeaderTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 90 * time.Second,
    TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
        GetCertificate: certManager.GetCertificate,
        ServerName: utilities.ServeHost,
    },
}

go func() {
    // serve HTTP, which will redirect automatically to HTTPS
    h := certManager.HTTPHandler(nil)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":http", h))
}()
log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServeTLS("", ""))
```

Recently, I have been running into an issue with long-running requests. I have an API call that takes approx. 45-60 seconds to complete.

I then have a client making a request with the following code:

```
req := &http.Request{
    Method:           http.MethodPatch,
    URL:              url,
    Header:           make(map[string][]string),
}
req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
res, e := utilities.GetClient().Do(req)
if e != nil {
    fmt.Print(err.Error())
    return
}
```

The client is defined as follows:

```
    client = &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        return http.ErrUseLastResponse
    },
    Jar:           nil,
    Timeout:       0,
}
```

When a client hits this endpoint though, after around 20 seconds, e is populated with the following message:

> Patch https://api.myapi.com/endpoint: stream error: stream ID 9; INTERNAL_ERROR

From what I can gather, this is somewhat related to [a write timeout](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/go1.9/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go#5371) however I set that to 90 seconds.

Comment: A note on terminology: There is no _throwing_ of errors (or anything else) in Go. Errors are just values. They are simply returned.

Comment: Good point, return seems more suitable :) thanks

Comment: Any luck adding a ReadTimeout to the server, or extending the ReadHeaderTimeout?

Comment: Unfortunately same problem. 60s ReadTimeout, ReadHeaderTimeout and WriteTimeout still results in the same issue after around 20 seconds.

Comment: Can you print and share the full error (with stacktrace): `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)`

Comment: Unfortunately no difference, exact same message.